# WPF ComboBox remove highlight effect without overriding entire style

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm new to WPF and have run into a bit of a problem. I am trying to remove the blue gradient effect on a combobox (e.g. when the user mouses over it) in order to create a more flat UI aesthetic, but I haven't been able to figure out how. Most of the solutions I've seen while googling involve doing somthing like:

```
<Style x:Key="myComboBox" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
    <!-- and then the rest of the style re-implements the combobox from scratch... -->
```

That seems a bit much just to remove one minor effect. I've also tried doing things like:

```
<Style x:Key="myComboBox" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="LightGray"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="DarkGray"/>
    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
```

But that doesn't seem to have any effect either. Does anyone know what setting I might change to remove the hover effect?

Comment: Have you tried adding `BasedOn` and then override the highlight only? I think it goes something like this: BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ComboBox}}".

Comment: @XAMlMAX I tried adding that but it didn't seem to change anything. I guess the real issue is that I don't know the property name of the thing that actually causes the highlight effect. I think I'm just going to copy/paste Microsoft's sample style for the combobox and incrementally change things until it looks the way I want...

Comment: You could have a look at the template and then look what property is responsible for the highlight effect. Chances are the template will be composed of multiple different UI elements, hence the style should target that type of UI element, if that makes sense.

Comment: [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/combobox-styles-and-templates) has a nice example of the ComboBox, you could just override the ColorBrush with key=ControlMouseOverColor and set it to whatever colour you want. Just put it in the Cmb Resources so it doesn't override that for any other controls.